# Dataframe conversion

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to convert a data frame into a 1,0 matrix format

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Val1':['A','B','B'],
                    'Val2':['C','A','D'],
                    'Val3':['E','F','C'],
                    'Comb':['Comb1','Comb2','Comb3']})
data:
  Val1 Val2 Val3   Comb
0    A    C    E  Comb1
1    B    A    F  Comb2
2    B    D    C  Comb3
```

What I need is to convert to below data frame

```
    Comb    A   C   D   E   B   F
0   Comb1   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   Comb2   1   0   0   0   1   1
2   Comb3   0   1   1   0   1   0
```

I was able to do it with a FOR loop but as my dataframe increases, the processing time increases. Is there a better way to do it?

```
header = set(data[['Val1','Val2','Val3']].values.ravel())
matrix = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    temp_dict = {data["Val1"].iloc[i]:1, data["Val2"].iloc[i]:1, data["Val3"].iloc[i]:1}
    matrix = matrix.append(temp_dict, ignore_index=True)
                    
matrix = matrix.loc[:, matrix.columns.notnull()]
matrix = matrix.fillna(0)
matrix = pd.merge(data[["Comb"]],matrix, left_index=True, right_index=True, how= 'outer')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one instance of any letter in each row?

Comment: No one letter will appear only once in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
data.melt('Comb').set_index('Comb')['value'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Comb  A  B  C  D  E  F
0  Comb1  1  0  1  0  1  0
1  Comb2  1  1  0  0  0  1
2  Comb3  0  1  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better solution, but this is what came to my mind: convert each raw to a dictionary of "present" letters, build a Series from the dictionary, and combine the Series into a dataframe.

```
data.loc[:, 'Val1':'Val3'].apply(lambda row: 
         pd.Series({letter: 1 for letter in row}), axis=1)\
    .fillna(0).astype(int).join(data.Comb)    
#   A  B  C  D  E  F   Comb
#0  1  0  1  0  1  0  Comb1
#1  1  1  0  0  0  1  Comb2
#2  0  1  1  1  0  0  Comb3
```

Answer (score 2):

There are propably multiple ways to solve this, I used `pd.crosstab` for it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Val1':['A','B','B'],
                    'Val2':['C','A','D'],
                    'Val3':['E','F','C'],
                    'Comb':['Comb1','Comb2','Comb3']})

data["lst"] = data[['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']].values.tolist()
data = data.explode("lst")

print(pd.crosstab(data["Comb"], data["lst"]))


Out[20]: 
lst    A  B  C  D  E  F
Comb                   
Comb1  1  0  1  0  1  0
Comb2  1  1  0  0  0  1
Comb3  0  1  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work. Please let me know if it works

```
 pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['Val1','Val2','Val3'],prefix="",prefix_sep="").groupby(axis=1,level=0).sum()
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, could you please let me know what you have changed ... I am not getting any diff